# ROR + Run Rake Job automatically after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

In Rails deployment, some times we missed to execute rake db:migrate, rake db:seed or any rake job after deploying the project at regular interval. I am trying to add such script with Rails structure, which will call RakeJob and all such type of script automatically after deployment.

Just like in this sequential way :-

rake db:migrate

rake db:seed

rake ( Here Rake is the combination of all rake jobs )

Comment: why not use capistrano for deployment ? it's very helpful and you can add any task to execute after deployment as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I normally deploy to Heroku. I am not sure where you are deploying to but here is a copy of my deploy script

```
#vim lib/tasks/deploy.rake

namespace :deploy do
  #rake deploy:production        # Deploy to production
  desc "Deploy to production"
  task :production do
    puts "THIS IS DEPLOYING TO PRODUCTION!!!"
    puts "********* CAREFUL! *********"
    sleep 10
    backup_environment_db("heroku-prod")
    deploy_sha_to_environment(ARGV[1], "heroku-prod")
    system("open http://www.example.com/")
  end

  def deploy_sha_to_environment(sha, environment)
    if sha = ARGV[1]
      puts "About to push #{sha} to #{environment}."
      message = `git log --format=%B -n 1 #{sha}`
      puts "#{sha} -- #{message}"
      sleep 2
      Bundler.with_clean_env do
        system "git push --force git@heroku.com:#{environment}.git #{sha}:master"
        system "heroku run rake db:migrate --app #{environment}"
        system "heroku restart --app #{environment}"
      end
    else
      puts
      puts "*** sha required! (pass it as an argument) ***"
      puts
      Rake.application.invoke_task("codeship:statuses")
      exit
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps